# Regex pattern misses match on a 2 char word

Tags: regex

Using regex101 I have developed this regex:

```
^(\S+)\s_(\S)(\S[^;\s]+)?.*
```

This works great for 99.999% of the time but occasionally it is run against a string containing a 2 char word that should have matched.

For example it would normally capture...

```
string _asdf = string.empty;
bool _ttfnow;
//$1 = string
//$2 = a
//$3 = sdf
and
//$1 = bool
//$2 = t
//$3 = tfnow
```

But for some reason this fails to match the third group?

```
string _qw = string.empty;
//$1 = string
//$2 = q
//$3 =
```

Again using regex101 if add add a char it suddenly matches so:

```
string _qwx = string.empty;
//$1 = string
//$2 = q
//$3 = wx
```

Any ideas? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\S+)\s_(\S)(\S[^;\s]*)?.*

                     ^^
```

Just change the quantifier.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/33

Comment: @user1278561 netime :)

Answer (score 1):

`[^;\s]+` change it to `[^;\s]*`

```
/^(\S+)\s_(\S)(\S[^;\s]*)?.*/
```